# Find a line in a list of .gz files

Tags: linux, shell, zcat

i around 50 .gz files in a particular directory in linux. i need to find a particular line in each file. currently i am doing by zcat each file.

Eg:

```
zcat 20160909-custfw.log.7.gz | zgrep BGP | zgrep  145.247.1.62
```

Output:

> Sep  9 17:12:47 145.247.1.62 cap-s12-custfw-1: NetScreen
>   device_id=cap-s12-custfw-1  [Root]system-information-00542: BGP peer
>   10.24.224.187 changed to Idle state (2016-09-09 17:13:15)

please let me if there is any easier way to do this.

Comment: I am surprised that the above actually works. zcat uncompresses the whole thing and prints everything to stdout. You are wasting a lot of cpu cycles for absolutely no reason here.

Comment: Besides. this site is about programming problems. Your question would rather go to unix.stackexchange.com for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search them in parallel with **GNU Parallel**:

```
parallel zgrep BGP {} ::: *.gz | grep 145.247.1.62
```

If you know it only occurs once in each file, or are only interested in the first occurrence, use `zgrep -m1` to avoid bothering to read the remainder of the file and stop on the first match.

Comment: thanks, this was exactly i was looking for, i want to check the first occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have `zgrep` installed, you shouldn't have to `zcat` the file. The entire point of zgrep is to let you grep gzipped files directly. Therefore, you should simply be able to do this:

```
zgrep BGP *.gz | grep 145.247.1.62
```

This should be slightly more performant as well.

Answer (score 1):

What about `zgrep 'BGP.*145.247.1.62' $dir/*.gz`?

(Or to achieve equivalent results to your sequence of two `zgrep` calls, you would have to zgrep also the inverse order of the two regexes, sth like `zgrep 'BGP.*145.247.1.62\|145.247.1.62.*BGP' $dir/*.gz`.)